# How can I share an authentication state across different test()?

Tags: node.js, playwright

I am trying to use an authentication state session for different test()
However Playwright is always starting a new page instance without using the authentication state "pre defined".
I tried with `beforeAll` and the `storageState` and no luck.

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
import { LoginPage } from '@pageRepo/login-page';
import { envConfig } from '@data/env-config';

test.beforeAll(async ({ page }) => {
    const loginStep = new LoginPage(page);
    await loginStep.uiAuthentication('/', envConfig.userEmail, envConfig.userPassword);
});

test('Please work', async ({ page }) => {
    const loginPage = new LoginPage(page);
    await loginPage.navigateToUrl('/dashboard');
});
```

When I run it is visible that the login is made under `beforeAll` but a new instance is loaded for `test('Please work')`
Using the `storageState` instead of `beforeAll` the json file with the cookies configuration is created but it is never used by the test.

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make the page instance global so it can be re-used across steps (if that's what you require) e.g.

```
let loginPage;

// best practise to start from a clean state on each test
test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
  loginPage = new LoginPage(page);
  await loginPage.uiAuthentication('/', envConfig.userEmail, envConfig.userPassword);
});

test('Please work', async ({ page }) => {
  // re-use the already created instance
  await loginPage.navigateToUrl('/dashboard');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Show please code of your storageState.

You need to prepare the Global configuration:
https://playwright.dev/docs/test-advanced#global-setup-and-teardown

Then define global setup in playwright.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from '@playwright/test';
export default defineConfig({
  **globalSetup: require.resolve('./global-setup'),**
  use: {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    **storageState: 'state.json',**
```

now in globalSetup you need to set authentication credationals by login + pass, or getting token by API.